# Configure Visual Studio Code for CMake with some options

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code

I want to use the [CMake Tools extension](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools) for developing a CMake project in Visual Studio Code.

I build the project in the command line with following command:

```
PS project\build> cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DBOOST_ROOT=some\path -DQT_ROOT=another\path\ project\path
```

How can I set the same command with same options in the `.cmaketools.json` file that I've under the `.vscode` folder? I want to run it from inside the editor and, if possible, specify also the output folder instead of creating a `build` folder inside my project one.

This is my actual `.cmaketools.json`:

```
{
  "variant": {
    "label": "Debug",
    "keywordSettings": {
      "buildType": "debug"
    },
    "description": "Emit debug information without performing optimizations"
  },
  "activeEnvironments": [
    "Visual C++ 14.0 - amd64"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `.vscode\.cmaketools.json` file is only the "workspace cache" of Visual Studio Code - CMake Tools Extension. See their [code](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/master/src/common.ts#L253):

> ```
> /**
>  * The workspace cache stores extension state that is convenient to remember
>  * between executions. Things like the active variant or enabled environments
>  * are stored here so that they may be recalled quickly upon extension
>  * restart.
> */
> ```

I think what you want is a `.vscode\settings.json` as described [here](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#conf-cmake-configuresettings) with e.g. the following content:

```js
{
    "cmake.generator": "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64",
    "cmake.configureSettings": { "BOOST_ROOT": "some/path", "QT_ROOT": "another/path" }
}
```

Comment: Your links seem to be broken.

Comment: I believe, the linked document is [here](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#conf-cmake-configuresettings) now.

Comment: Specifying QT_ROOT did not work for me, but the following did:

``"cmake.configureArgs" : [
        "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\\projects\\qt"
    ]``

Comment: @SebastianK according documentation ( https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html ): 

Warning: Always prefer to use cmake.configureSettings or CMake Variants. Never pass -D arguments using this setting.