# Cmake Compiler Issue

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mingw

I am trying to setup `cmake` using Windows 10 using `MinGW`. I have included the path `c:/MinGW/bin` in my system path and environment path settings. I have removed `sh.exe` from my path (although, i would love to be able to keep this if possible).

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")

project (Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cpp)
```

Output

```
C:\School\athabascua\data structures\ass1>cmake -g "MinGW Makefiles" .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_b3144\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/School/athabascua/data structures/ass1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_b3144\fast"



Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
"cmTC_b3144\fast"
```

It seems that the GNU compilers are identified but don't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to avoid using Cygwin.. but almost ready to go that route in a sec here.

Comment: It looks like cmake is configured for Microsoft's toolchain, because it's trying to run `nmake`.

Comment: okay, maybe this is because i'm using Visual Studio Code, i will look into installing nmake. Thanks for the input

Comment: I would rather suggest telling cmake to use GNU make instead of MS nmake.  Try `cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles"` instead of `cmake -G"NMake Makefiles"`   See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Generator_Specific_Information#Makefile_generators

Comment: Or in VS Code, [set `cmake.generator` as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42462406/103167), but use `MinGW Makefiles`

Comment: Thank you Ben. It is compiling now. The problem was that I was using `cmake -g "MinGW Makefiles"` and having a lowercase `-g` seemed to cause the problem because when I use uppercase `-G` it works. Good ol windows

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm experiencing an issue where `make` is failing to link `standard c++ libraries`. I have attempted to include the standard libraries in my `c_cpp_properties.json` file for visual studio code as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath but this did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it linking using `ld`, `gcc`, or `g++`?  Usually it's best to set the link tool to `g++` since that will automatically add the options for the C++ libraries and then call `ld`.

Comment: Or maybe you just need to change `gcc.exe` to `g++.exe` in the rules you already showed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem I was having, I had to do two things.

1. use the command `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .` (capital -G on windows)
2. update my `CMakeLists.txt` file to use gcc for C compiler and g++ for C++ compiler

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe")

project (Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cpp)
```

Comment: Yeah `gcc` and `g++` both run the same compiler, but with different default options.  And for the link step, the files are all named `*.o` so the filename provides no hint that C++ libraries should be used.

Comment: Just FYI, you can avoid setting the variables in the CMakeLists.txt and thus keep your program portable by instead specifying them on the command line `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"`.