# this error happened when I run flutter project in vscode how can i solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find annotations-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.1.0/annotations-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-4.1.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/4.1.0/databinding-common-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/4.1.0/baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: The error message should be much longer. See e.g. the one in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837313/cmake-compiler-issue). Also make sure that you have checked other questions with the same error message.

Comment: Normally, a question post contains much more than just a error message. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: i know it have more than error message 
in debug console the errors come like this