# CMake to create a Visual Studio Code project

Tags: linux, cmake

Does anyone know if there are any efforts for cmake to generate a Visual Studio Code project (not to be confused with Visual Studio)? IE

> cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

- not for eclipse, but for Visual Studio *Code*? This would be awesome for linux projects.

Comment: I'm using the "Open Folder" feature with the [CMake Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vector-of-bool.cmake-tools). No need to have e.g. workspace definitions generated. For an example setup see e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423536/configure-visual-studio-code-for-cmake-with-some-options).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does it allow you to compile and debug within the IDE? I would love to replace Eclipse IDE with VSCode.

Comment: [yes it does](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, VS Code has [the vscode-cmake-tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) to integrate with CMake projects.

See [here for documentation on what features it has to offer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/README.md). You will see that building and debugging within the IDE are supported.

The design of VS Code is very much centered around being simple and extensible, whereas Visual Studio is more of a monolith and includes its own build system for C++. VS Code is not monolithic like that.