# CMake generator in Visual Studio Code Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have installed VS Code under Windows 10 to compile C++ code for Raspberry Pi Pico.  When I try to build the pico examples VS complains "Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable."

I have installed CMake and CMake Tools in the IDE.  What is a CMake generator, why do I need one and how do I install it in VS Code?  The only documentation I can find seems to lead down a rabbit hole of more things I don't understand like Toolchain, MSYS2, MinGW and so on.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-presets.md)

Comment: "What is a CMake generator, why do I need one and how do I install it in VS Code?" - The duplicate question describes what is CMake generator. In VSCode you could set generator among other options for your project. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423536). "The only documentation I can find seems to lead down a rabbit hole of more things I don't understand like Toolchain, MSYS2, MinGW and so on." - Since you want to **cross-compile** (build code on Windows but run it on Raspberry Pi), you need to learn these things.